# How to create the first object if only copy constructor is declared?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, default-constructor

I saw a C++03 example online today.

```
class Cat {
    public:
        Cat(const Cat& iCat);
};
```

I was told that in this case, no default constructor will be automatically generated by compiler. If it is true, this means new Cat object can be created from an existing Cat object.

Can anyone tell me how to create the first Cat object in this case? or kindly correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: "Can anyone tell me how to create the first Cat object in this case?" - you can't. So don't write code like that.

Comment: Perhaps this example was purely for illustration?  In reasonable code you would want to have an additional constructor, whether or not it's a default constructor.

Comment: I'd suggest you need to at least extend your class with a private constructor and a function to get a base class initialized to some sensible defaults if you don't want it to be generally constructible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the valid answer should be that there is no way to create the first `Cat`. The example was probably only pulled out to demonstrate how a user-declared constructor will prevent the implicitly-declared default constructor to be declared.

---

Now, in spite of this, and purely if the means justifies the ends, there is, however, ways of creating the first cat using a *layout-compatible* object.

C++11 introduced **layout compatibility:**

> Two standard-layout struct (Clause 9) types are layout-compatible if they have the same number of non-static data members and corresponding non-static data members (in declaration order) have layout-compatible types (3.9).
>
> ---
>
> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
>     *has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.
>
> A standard-layout struct is a standard-layout class defined with the class-key `struct` or the class-key `class`.

This means that you can do:

```
class Cat {
public:
    Cat(const Cat& iCat) : x{iCat.x} {}
    int x;
};

class foo {
public:
    foo(int x) : m_x{x} {}
    int m_x;
};

int main() {
    foo f{5};
    Cat* c1 = reinterpret_cast<Cat*>(&f);
    Cat c2 = *c1;
    std::cout << c2.x << std::endl; // 5
}
```

The `x` and `m_x` members are used to demonstrate the copying of (layout-compatible) members.

*Note: As mentioned in comment by [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43988835/how-to-create-the-first-object-if-only-copy-constructor-is-declared#comment75008817_43989740), you might need to disable strict aliasing in your compiler for this to work.*

Comment: This violates the strict aliasing rule (even though the classes have the same layout)

Comment: @M.M Hmm, so you need to disable strict aliasing in the compiler for this to work. Or maybe use a union somehow?

Comment: Yeah. Your answer inspired me to write one using the union common-initial-sequence rule although I am not convinced that my answer isn't UB also

Answer (score 5):

> Can anyone tell me how to create the first Cat object in this case? or kindly correct me if my understanding is wrong.

The only valid answer here is:

There is no way only using the code you posted. You probably missed some additional functionality that was given along with that example you saw.

---

There are ways though if any other constuctor is declared `private`, e.g.:

```
class Cat {
    public:
        Cat(const Cat& iCat);
        static Cat* CreateCat(const std::string& color) {
            return new Cat(color);
        }
    private:
        Cat(const std::string& color)
};
```

Comment: I wanted to comment that private constructor is also commonly used to implement the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of C++14 [class.mem]/18:

> If a standard-layout union contains two or more standard-layout structs that share a common initial sequence,
>   and if the standard-layout union object currently contains one of these standard-layout structs, it is permitted
>   to inspect the common initial part of any of them. Two standard-layout structs share a common initial
>   sequence if corresponding members have layout-compatible types and either neither member is a bit-field or
>   both are bit-fields with the same width for a sequence of one or more initial members.

`Cat` is standard-layout, so we can make a union that contains two types of common initial sequence.   Any two standard-layout classes with no data members meet the criteria for having a common initial sequence, so:

```
class Cat {
    public: Cat(const Cat& iCat);
};

class Dog {
    public: Dog();
};

union CatDog
{
    Dog dog;
    Cat cat;
};

int main()
{
    CatDog horse{};
    Cat cat(horse.cat);
}
```

---

*Note:* The standard does not precisely define the meaning of "inspect the common initial part".  If the common initial part coincides with the entirety of the struct, does that mean the entire struct can be inspected as in my code? I guess that is a question for the language-lawyers.

Answer (score -2):

You can do this, although it's **not at all recommended**; doing what's show below is **very very bad** practice and leads to "Undefined behavior"

```
 const Cat* pCat = nullptr;
 const Cat& cat = *pCat; // yikes! NULL reference...boo!
 Cat fluffy(cat);
```

If you're trying to doing something like this, you're probably approaching the problem *in a completely wrong way*, and you should **rethink** your solution.

Comment: Please don't. From this answer at least it can be learned what UB is.

Answer (score -2):

**Don't do the following in production code**, but for the case of illustration, the following worked with "gcc 5.4.0".

As there is UB (undefined behaviour) involved, using std::string here e.g. as a member variable of cat, the example is stripped down to:

For the sake of bringing a 'cat' to life, you could do some reinterpret-cast to create your 'first' cat:

```cpp
class Cat {
    public:
        Cat(const Cat& iCat) {
        }
};

int main() {        
    Cat* cat = reinterpret_cast<Cat*>(new char[sizeof(Cat)]);
    Cat cat2 = Cat(*cat);
    delete cat;
}
```

**Again, the above code is just for illustration purpose, only worked on gcc 5.4.0 and does not guarantee that it works with other compilers.**

There is the chance to easily introduce UB in the code, by expanding it as explained in the comments e.g:

```
#include <iostream>

class Cat {
    private:
        std::string name_;
    public:
        Cat(const Cat& iCat) {
           this->name_ = iCat.name_;
        }
        void setName(const std::string& name) { name_ = name; }
        const std::string& name() { return name_; }
};

int main() {        
    Cat* cat = reinterpret_cast<Cat*>(new char[sizeof(Cat)]);
    cat->setName("Lilly");
    Cat cat2 = Cat(*cat);
    std::cout << cat2.name() << std::endl;
    delete cat;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: πάντα ῥεῖ Can you explain, in which statement exactly UB is involved?

Comment: @cwschmidt E.g. here `cat->setName("Lilly");` or here `cat2.name()`.

Comment: There is UB in several places, for example ` void setName(const std::string& name) { name_ = name; }` and `cat->setName("Lilly");`

Comment: Ok, I see .. but the question was to create an initial cat, so I thought more about the reinterpret_cast. That name was just for illustration (Btw. I tested with gcc 5.4.0 and ran valgrind).

Comment: If UB behavior happens to work in any given version, that is luck.  There is no guarantee it will continue to do so in the future and is therefore a bad idea.

Comment: "Btw. I tested with gcc 5.4.0 " - did you actually run the code? There is an approaching zero chance your code could possibly "work", even given the vagaries of UB.

Comment: http://cpp.sh properly detects this as UB.  Go paste it in and run it a few dozen times.

Comment: @Donnie: I see (and understood), that using std::string as name is causing UB, but (as I already asked) what if I remove all the name-thing from the code? E.g. if I replace 'std::string name_' with a 'int x_' for illustration.

Comment: `Cat(*cat);` causes UB  (there is no Cat object at `*cat` location, just storage with no objects in it) regardless of whether Cat contains a string etc.